# How to compare Enum in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

in Objective-C this works fine

[image]

Can't compile this in Swift

[image]

Or

[image]

ALAuthorizationStatus definition in IOS SDK

```
enum ALAuthorizationStatus : Int {
    case NotDetermined // User has not yet made a choice with regards to this application
    case Restricted // This application is not authorized to access photo data.
    // The user cannot change this application’s status, possibly due to active restrictions
    //  such as parental controls being in place.
    case Denied // User has explicitly denied this application access to photos data.
    case Authorized // User has authorized this application to access photos data.
}
```

Comment: Please show us your enum definition.

Comment: AssetsLibrary from IOS SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison operator `==` returns a `Bool`, not `Boolean`.
The following compiles:

```
func isAuthorized() -> Bool {
    let status = ALAssetsLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    return status == ALAuthorizationStatus.Authorized
}
```

(Personally, I find the error messages from the Swift compiler sometimes confusing.
In this case, the problem was not the arguments of `==`,  but the incorrect return type.)

---

Actually, the following should also compile due to the *automatic type inference:*

```
func isAuthorized() -> Bool {
    let status = ALAssetsLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    return status == .Authorized
}
```

But it fails with the compiler error **"Could not find member 'Authorized'"**, unless you
explicitly specify the type of the `status` variable:

```
func isAuthorized() -> Bool {
    let status:ALAuthorizationStatus = ALAssetsLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    return status == .Authorized
}
```

This could be a bug in the current Swift compiler (tested with Xcode 6 beta 1).

**Update:** The first version now compiles in Xcode 6.1.